# Windows (10 and Server 2019): Why suddenly Search Active Directory button is greyed out (disabled)?

Tags: windows, active-directory, gui

I do not understand this unexpected behavior: I'm making some experiments with VMWare Workstation 16 Pro and few virtual machines with Windows 10 Pro (20H2) and Windows Server 2019 Standard. I put Windows 10 machines on a domain and, for a while, I did not have any kind of trouble: I could click the **Search Active Directory** button in the **Network** window for opening the useful **Find Users, Contacts, and Groups** window. Now, without any kind of reason (I did not make any change and no computer has access to Internet) the **Search Active Directory** button is greyed out on all the computers, Server 2019 machine included
[image]

I can open the **Find Users, Contacts, and Groups** window, digiting `Rundll32 dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow` but how can I reenable that useful button? I do not want to install something on the computers, since the button had worked fine for a while on each computer.

***MORE:***
Everything works fine: domain works fine and computers can see each others as usual: the only issue is about the **Search Active Directory** button and, repeat, no machine accesses to Internet and never I made updates

Comment: Has the machine installed any recent updates?  If the machines have been updated, which updates specifically, have been installed?  Are you positive that the machine and AD server can still communicate?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I found the reason for that behavior: it is one of the limitations due to the fact that Windows is not activated: even if you install it without a serial key, you can use the o.s. without any limitations, until you do not access to Internet but, if the machine accesses Internet, even if for few minutes, then you have to activate Windows or you have to endure certain types of limitations like the inability to change background images or manage icons on the taskbar from Settings (you can do that but in another fashion,  e.g. via `Regedit` or third-party tools). Anyway, one of these limitations is that the **Search Active Directory** button is greyed out. In my case, probably there was a moment in which machines went to Internet (but I do not remember) and, since I have installed them skipping serial keys, Windows wanted to be activated: from this moment on, the **Search Active Directory** button  became greyed out. When I tried to activate the machines, the problem was fixed and the button is back.

Comment: For UI-Fetishists: 
If a UI-Element is greyed out it should be mandatory to have a tooltip explain the reason for deactivating the element.. It wopuld make a lot interaction more understandable